# Intellij IDEA can not find tools.jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-15

I install Intellij IDEA 15.0.2 on Windows 8.1, run it, it asked for the path to jdk, i choose directory with JDK, and then IDEA worked correctly. But after reload of PC, I get this error message from IDEA - `'tools.jar' seems to be not in IDEA classpath.`.So, I check JAVA_HOME from command line, check for tools.jar in `JDK_directory/lib`, everything is on their places, how to run IDEA?

Answer (score 4):

Open IDEA. Select [File]-[Invalidate Caches/Restart] menu and select "Invalidate and Restart" button. Have a try. :-)

Comment: I can not even open IDEA, it shutdowns after this error message.

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't set up JAVA_HOME. Try to add `JAVA_HOME=</path/to/JDK>` variable to your PATH. For example `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66`

Comment: I check it from command line, JAVA_HOME set up, for example, eclipse, which uses same jdk, works as well.

Comment: And I check PATH variable too, everything is correct there.

Answer (score 1):

A few years later, this still persists. I had this issue with java 16 and IntelliJ has it logged [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-243962) as well. I tried a bunch of things including invalidating the cache and restarting. No luck.

Try Updating IntelliJ as they suggest in the linked website. That did the trick for me. FWIW, I was on IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 and updated to 2021.2.

Answer (score 0):

By deafault, idea.exe runs, but if you run instead idea64.exe, everything works correctly.